# PHP display $value only once until $value changes

Tags: php

Hi I have the following table that is generated from my database, it looks like this

[image]

The problem is I dont want the dates to repeat. If there is more than one fixture for a specific date, I only want the **date displayed once** and then the fixtures under the date.

Example In this case, on the image, *Today,2015-04-23* must be displayed only once and then the 2 team names under it.

Im using the following code

```
$echoed = false;

while($row = > $played){

$gameDate = $row['event_date'];
$team1 = $row['team1'];
$team2 = $row['team2'];
$venue = $row['venue'];
$eventId = $row['event_id'];



    if($gameDate == $date && !$echoed){

    echo'<tr>'; 
    echo $echoed ='<td>Today,'.$gameDate.'echo</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
    echo'<tr>';
        echo'<td>'.$team1.'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$team2.'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$venue.'</td>';
        :
        :
```

However code above is not giving desired result and returns result same as per image above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check, if the date is the same as the one before:

```
<?php
$lastDate = '';

while($row = > $played){

$gameDate = $row['event_date'];
$team1 = $row['team1'];
$team2 = $row['team2'];
$venue = $row['venue'];
$eventId = $row['event_id'];
if($gameDate !== $lastDate) {
echo'<tr>';
  $lastDate = $gamedate;
  echo $echoed ='<td>Today,'.$gameDate.'echo</td>';
echo'</tr>';
}
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td>'.$team1.'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$team2.'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$venue.'</td>';
```

Note: i removed your echoed code and your if-statement, because $date is undefined :)

Comment: You would need `!==` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$echoed` the way you do, you can use the `$date` variable only to keep track of the current date you are printing for. Then you only print the date itself when it changes.

Something like:

```
// I am using $date as it seems undefined, but if you already use that, name it something else
$date = false;

while($row = > $played){

  $gameDate = $row['event_date'];
  $team1 = $row['team1'];
  $team2 = $row['team2'];
  $venue = $row['venue'];
  $eventId = $row['event_id'];

  if($gameDate !== $date){
    $date = $gameDate;
    echo'<tr>'; 
    echo $echoed ='<td>Today,'.$gameDate.'echo</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
  }
  echo'<tr>';
  echo'<td>'.$team1.'</td>';
  echo'<td>'.$team2.'</td>';
  echo'<td>'.$venue.'</td>';
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the last date in each loop and just check with date in current step.

```
$last_date = '';

while (...) {
    $gameDate = $row['event_date'];
    // set other variables

    if ($gameDate != $last_date) {
        // write $gameDate here
    }

    // teams table here    

    $last_date = $gameDate;
}
```

Comment: This will not work, even if you use `!=` as you are setting the `$last_date` always at the end of your loop.

Comment: @jeroen: of course, just typo... Thanks, I've updated the post.

Comment: Check my comment again ;-)

Comment: @jeroen: no, now it works correctly. Really. There was just bad operator, `==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: No, you only change `$last_date` when the condition is met, now it will only work the first time but not when the date changes.

Comment: @jeroen: no, you're not right. You can try it :-) `$last_date` is outside the condition (and was). Now I've just put there comments, but the logic stays the same.

Comment: Nope, just follow the flow of the program, as you set your variable always at the end of the loop, the conditions will never be met again after the first time / iteration.